# Trigger other DAG's and mark the current job as success

Tags: python-3.x, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am using TriggerDAGRunOperator to trigger other DAG's but the current job is waiting until those DAGs executed. My requirement is that current DAG should be marked as success as soon as it trigger others.

For example below is the job, as soon as the current job triggers three parallel tasks the current job must be marked as "success" as its job is done. Present behavior is the current job is waiting until other triggered DAGs are executed and its status depends on whether others are success/failed.

[image]

Here is the current code

```
t0 = DummyOperator(task_id="start")
   
bi_triad_eom_validation_process = BashOperator(
   
)

bi_triad_eom_validation_process_send_email = EmailOperator(
    task_id="bi_triad_eom_validation_process_send_email",
)

trigger_bi_triad_eom_validation_dashboard = TriggerDagRunOperator(
    task_id='trigger_bi_triad_eom_validation_dashboard',
    trigger_dag_id='bi_triad_eom_validation_dashboard',
    wait_for_completion=True
)

trigger_line_item_direct_pacing_variance = TriggerDagRunOperator(
    task_id='trigger_line_item_direct_pacing_variance',
    trigger_dag_id='line_item_direct_pacing_variance'
)

trigger_line_item_axt_pacing_variance = TriggerDagRunOperator(
    task_id='trigger_line_item_axt_pacing_variance',
    trigger_dag_id='line_item_axt_pacing_variance'
)

trigger_bidl_finance_invoice_automation_gate_2 = TriggerDagRunOperator(
    task_id='trigger_bidl_finance_invoice_automation_gate_2',
    trigger_dag_id='bidl_finance_invoice_automation_gate_2'
)

t0  >> bi_triad_eom_validation_process >> bi_triad_eom_validation_process_send_email >> [trigger_bi_triad_eom_validation_dashboard ,trigger_line_item_axt_pacing_variance , trigger_line_item_direct_pacing_variance]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not immediately marking as success for two reasons:

```
trigger_bi_triad_eom_validation_dashboard = TriggerDagRunOperator(
    task_id='trigger_bi_triad_eom_validation_dashboard',
    trigger_dag_id='bi_triad_eom_validation_dashboard',
    wait_for_completion=True
)
```

The `wait_for_completion=True` will block the current dag until `bi_triad_eom_validation_dashboard` has completed.

I can see why you've done this because you want to trigger `bidl_finance_invoice_automation_gate_2` conditionally, only if `bi_triad_eom_validation_dashboard` succeeds.

Move

```
trigger_bidl_finance_invoice_automation_gate_2 = TriggerDagRunOperator(
    task_id='trigger_bidl_finance_invoice_automation_gate_2',
    trigger_dag_id='bidl_finance_invoice_automation_gate_2'
)
```

Into `bi_triad_eom_validation_dashboard`. Then remove `wait_for_completion=True` in

```
trigger_bi_triad_eom_validation_dashboard = TriggerDagRunOperator(
    task_id='trigger_bi_triad_eom_validation_dashboard',
    trigger_dag_id='bi_triad_eom_validation_dashboard',
    wait_for_completion=True
)
```

and you will have the behaviour you're after.